# Downloading file from websites with login using browser cookie

Tags: c#, .net, http, cookies, authentication

I am writing a file download utility, it has a companion browser extension. For public download URLs it work fine. Now I am trying to download file from website which require login. I am using google drive as example. Here's what I have done so far-

- Extension intercepts the download in the browser (chrome) and extracts the URL and fetches "Cookie" from the browser corresponding to the url. The cookie looks something like this - "AUTH_cotobe...mreoe3b9u=12465193…|154...000|dr5hgc...jnkkrls".
- `HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
  request.Headers["Cookie"] = cookieStringFromBrowser;
  request.UserAgent = userAgentFromBrowser;
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`
- The `response.ResponseUri` is similar to "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1....." and the `response.Headers["set-cookie"]` has a cookie in it.

From here I am not sure how to proceed, I was expecting the response in step (2) to have the file details given I passed the cookie from the browser where the user was already logged in.

So, given a download URL and the browser cookie for it, how do I get the file details or download the file?